# How to bind object properties to a set of textboxes in a new window

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm creating an application and when a user Clicks a certain item in a new Window is created and an object is passed as an input parameter.

```
private void GridItem_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Grid item = (Grid)sender;
    int itemId = Convert.ToInt32(item.Tag) - 1;
    Bill_Overview BO = new Bill_Overview(Bills[itemId]);
    BO.ShowDialog();
    BO.Owner = this;
}
```

Inside the window cs file there's this:

```
public DBConnection.Bill Bill { get; set; }

public Bill_Overview(DBConnection.Bill bill)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Bill = bill;
}
```

and inside the wpf of the Bill_Overview window I'd like to bind each property of the Property Bill, but whatever I've tried it doesn't work. I have this as my current set up, which doesn't work.

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding Bill}">
    <TextBox Margin="0,28,0,185" Text="{Binding Path=Payer, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    ...
</Grid>
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? I've tried to look for a solution for quite a bit, but nothing seems to be working.

Cheers!

Comment: Your property doesn't notify the binding engine when it changes, therefore the view doesn't know it needs to update. I'd advise you to read on the subject so you understand the root cause instead of a quick fix.

Comment: I remember this being something about INotifyPropertyChanged, right? But I don't know how to implement that (yet). However solution given by Eyal does the trick and serves the purpose of the window :)

Comment: My point exactly. It fixes this specific issue while you didn't fully understand why. You should try a hands-on approach on data binding and WPF (there are plenty of tutorials online).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the DataContext assignment expression from your xaml

```
DataContext="{Binding Bill}"
```

Then in C#, do this:

```
public DBConnection.Bill Bill { get; set; }

public Bill_Overview(DBConnection.Bill bill)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Bill = bill;
    DataContext = bill;
}
```

(DataContext is inherited by the logical children of an element, so assigning the window's DataContext effectively updates all the children's DataContext unless they set their own value, which is what you did with the Grid.

Also, since the C# property *Bill* is not a Dependency Property, assigning it will not trigger an update and the window will continue using the initial (null) value.

Comment: Well this was simple.. And it even works with TwoWay binding.. Great! :)

Comment: cheers.. I really recommend you have a look at the Dependency Property mechanism and understand it better.. it is very important if you intend to use XAML as a tool of trade.